# How to make two node cluster of postgres in google cloud?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I am currently working on google cloud sql. where i have make one single instance of postgres server. i want to build two node postgres cluster with both nodes active.
How can i built it. any help/tutorial or link regarding to it will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cloud SQL for Postgres Beta currently does not support any form of High Availability [1].

If this is something you require immediately, you would need to run the nodes yourself or use another solution.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/high-availability